# Ubuntu 12.04 low screen resolution

Tags: resolution

After installing Ubuntu 12.04LTS I tried to change my screen resolution from 640 by 480 to the one suitable for my system but discovered that I cannot. I tried xrandr but it did not work out. Please what can I do to get the best resolution for my system. The resolution I use on windows is 1280 by 800. How can I get same on Ubuntu or something close to that as the maximum resolution on my linux is the 640 by 480?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top left (in unity) and search for 'additional drivers'. Install the recommended or proprietary drivers. You might have to reboot. If this doesn't work, add a comment on this answer and I'll try again.